# Map not loading and shows empty screen with black icons

Tags: android, routes, navigation, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am using 'sdktools' for calculating routes and navigation. Meanwhile i am getting this issue in design, I tried with 'preserveGLContext' to true in the mapView. How can i solve this issue?

[image: map on route calculation]

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your app architecture I can't provide a lot of feedback - can you replicate this behaviour in the demo project? (your map seems corrupted but I can't tell what is happening behind the scenes to arrive at this scenario).

When using multiple map views make sure that the GLSurfaceView is notified when the activity is paused and resumed. GLSurfaceView clients are required to call onPause() when the activity pauses and onResume() when the activity resumes. These calls allow GLSurfaceView to pause and resume the rendering thread, and also allow GLSurfaceView to release and recreate the OpenGL display.